# Why Etherscan can not verify contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, etherscan

I'm faced with issue, can't verify contract after deploy.

Maybe some one has the same issue?

Code and tx

```
https://gist.github.com/RuslanMirov/4f034f7ad5ecbea646efdbbd3110c8bc
```

Video with my attemp

```
https://youtu.be/Dzn8JDPng6o
```

Deploy settings

```
Compiler version 0.6.12, optimization - yes
```